# Use of boot.scr file on Android beagleboard

Tags: android, linux, beagleboard

Can anyone tell the sequence for Android booting?
What i know is :
1)First, the ROM boots 
2)Then, it looks for MLO,which is the first external boot loader.
3)Then, u-boot file which is the second external boot loader.
4) Then, linux kernel is set up using uimage file which mounts the filesystem (rootfs).

Where in the above sequence boot.scr came into?
I think it is the boot file which has the options for booting. correct? Does, the ROM of beagleboard searches for boot.scr or MLO?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to figure this out by the location of the file and/or its contents.  Which stages might realistically find it? Which might care about the kinds of things mentioned in its contents?

Comment: I thought I would get a straight forward answer to my question rather than just by going to the file itself and checking...

Comment: Anyone to answer????

Comment: It's kind of odd that you'd **waste days of time** hoping for a response here rather than *simply looking in the file* to see what you could learn from it.